# How to prove the equality of $E[E(Y|F)^2]$ and $Y^2$? Alternatively, how to prove that conditional expectation is an orthogonal projection?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I stumbled on this very interesting question that wants me to prove

$$ E[Y^2] = E[E(Y|F)^2] + E[(Y-E(Y|F))^2].$$

Which means that the conditional expectation is an orthogonal projection and it satisfies the Pythagorean identity. By expansion and simplification, I found that I just need to show that $E[E(Y|F)^2] = YE[E(Y|F)]$ or, alternatively, that $E[E(Y|F)^2] = Y^2 $. Can I simply use the law of total expectation? Thanks a lot for the help! I am really struggling with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need $E[E(Y|F)^2] = YE[E(Y|F)]$ (which is not true). What you need is the fact that both sides of this have the same expectation: $E[E[E(Y|F)^2]] = E[YE[E(Y|F)]]$. To prove this start with RHS and use the tower property. When you condition on $F$ you get $E[YE[E(Y|F)]]=E[ E[YE[E(Y|F)]]|F]$. Now pull out the the inside $E(Y|F)$ : It is already measuarble w.r.t. $F$). Now you get LHS easily.

Comment: Wow, this was a great answer! I was really insecure on some properties.

Comment: Actually, I have one more question, why would proving that both have the same expectation be the solution? I think this is the last thing I don't understand

Comment: When you expanded the square what you needed was the fact that the two sides have the same expectation. [After all you are not proving any equality among random variables; you only want equality of num bers]. If you go back to that step you wil see the reason.  @callmemathy